# PythonAnywhere .py file upload not working

Tags: python, html, flask, file-permissions, pythonanywhere

This all started when I wanted to deploy my first flask app, and when uploading my .py file into pythonanywhere.com I encountered a problem which stated that:

`Permission denied: You do not have write permissions for directory /.`

I was wondering why this is the case and how I can solve it. This is my file that I was wanting to upload: `/Users/stepan/Documents/GettingStarted/main.py`. It contains a simple flask app, with a simple index.html file that outputs Hello World.

I am very confused on why this error is being outputted. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don’t believe this is answerable by anyone except your provider’s support team. Stack Overflow is not a replacement for such a resource.

Comment: You should reach out to PythonAnywhere's support - support@pythonanywhere.com

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to / on PythonAnywhere. Upload the file into place where you have write permissions - somewhere under /home/stepan